# I want to fetch days from column in mysql table only if it matches with the current day

Tags: php, mysql

I want to fetch days from column in MySQL table only if it matches with the current day [This Image Represents column in my table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjpIk.png)

How to do this?

Comment: Have u tried any thing?

Comment: Yeah, But it didnt work. I tried this query SELECT * FROM loo_list WHERE  `days` = CURRENT_DAY()

Comment: Users on StackOverflow will help you, **after you help yourself**. Do some research: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527.
Learn how to post good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  And http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Look at mysql documentation, SELECT and dates.  A web search will show you tons of examples.

Comment: I searched many stackoverflow questions but it didnt help me

Comment: Dude!  Put this in Google: "mysql select date today", first link is the exact same thing, from this site!

Comment: I want only day

Comment: Mon, Tue, Thurs ... a bit of consistency might help you here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one SELECT * FROM table_name where days = DAYNAME( CURRENT_DATE() )

Comment: which type of column "days" are you using?

Comment: Hope this will help you 
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE days IN (DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY),'%a'))

Comment: No luck  bro !!. it didnt help